# importing multiple .csv files and selecting same variabls from multiple data frames using r

Tags: r

Using R I am wanting to import several .csv files using a loop function. The .csv files are the same data over several months
example:

```
Datafile_Jan19.csv
Datafile_Feb19.csv
Datafile_Mar19.csv
Datafile_Apr19.csv
```

So instead of typing out the import code for each file:

```
Jan19 = import("C:/Users/Manfred Kuhn/Documents/Board Report/Mozambique/Datafile_Jan19.csv", 
               integer64 = "double")
```

Secondly from each file I would like to select only specific variables:

```
Jan19new = Jan19 %>% 
  select(CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_NAME, ACCOUNT_ID, PERIOD, TIME_ON_BOOK, 
         ORIGINATION_DATE,  MATURITY_DATE, LIMIT, PRODUCT_LEVEL1, PRODUCT_LEVEL2, 
         ARREARS_STATUS)
```

Can this variable selection be done in a loop?

Comment: `data.table`'s `fread` offers `select` argument to specify which columns to keep up-front. You can easily loop over files like `f = list.files('.', pattern = 'csv')` and then `for (F in f) fread(F, select=...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of the files and load all of them choosing only the variables you need with plyr::ldply:

```
#Set data location
path <- "files_path"

#Get files
file <- list.files(path)

#Load Data
data <- plyr::ldply(paste(path,file,sep = ""), read_csv,locale = locale(encoding = "WINDOWS-1252"))
```